# SonarQube Not Starting When Using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

We are upgrading from SonarQube 5.6 to 6.7.1.  I've created a new folder for 6.7.1 to live in and uninstalled SonarQube.  We've added the new plugins from the market and updated the config files for 6.7.1.  Using the internal DB, we're good.  However, as soon as we switch it to use SQL Server, the service fails.

Here are the changes to the sonar.properties file:

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://[SQL Server FQDN];databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=false
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar_user
sonar.jdbc.password=[password]

Here is the TRACE level output in the sonar.log:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.02.15 09:38:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\temp
2018.02.15 09:38:52 TRACE app[][o.s.a.NodeLifecycle] tryToMoveTo from INIT to STARTING => true
2018.02.15 09:38:52 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from INIT to STARTING => true
2018.02.15 09:38:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.15 09:38:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\temp\conf\es
2018.02.15 09:38:52 TRACE app[][o.s.a.p.Lifecycle] tryToMoveTo es from STARTING to STARTED => true
2018.02.15 09:38:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.02.15 09:38:53 TRACE app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.02.15 09:38:53 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [force_merge], size [1], queue size [unbounded]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [fetch_shard_started], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [listener], size [1], queue size [unbounded]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [index], size [1], queue size [200]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [refresh], core [1], max [1], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [generic], core [4], max [128], keep alive [30s]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [warmer], core [1], max [1], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [search], size [2], queue size [1k]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [flush], core [1], max [1], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [fetch_shard_store], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [management], core [1], max [5], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [get], size [1], queue size [1k]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [bulk], size [1], queue size [200]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.t.ThreadPool] created thread pool: name [snapshot], core [1], max [1], keep alive [5m]
2018.02.15 09:38:53 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.n.IfConfig] configuration:

lo
        Software Loopback Interface 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask:255.0.0.0 broadcast:127.255.255.255 scope:host
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen:128 scope:host
        UP MULTICAST LOOPBACK mtu:-1 index:1

net0
        WAN Miniport (L2TP)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:2

net1
        WAN Miniport (SSTP)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:3

net2
        WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:4

net3
        WAN Miniport (PPTP)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:5

ppp0
        WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:6

eth0
        WAN Miniport (IP)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:7

eth1
        WAN Miniport (IPv6)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:8

eth2
        WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:9

eth3
        Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:10

ppp1
        RAS Async Adapter
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:11

eth4
        Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
        inet 10.50.8.41 netmask:255.255.255.0 broadcast:10.50.8.255 scope:site
        inet6 fe80::9407:eb78:32b6:4195 prefixlen:64 scope:link
        hardware 00:15:5D:02:44:6E
        UP MULTICAST mtu:1500 index:12

net4
        Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
        inet6 fe80::5efe:a32:829 prefixlen:128 scope:link
        hardware 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:E0
        POINTOPOINT mtu:1280 index:13

eth5
        WAN Miniport (IP)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:14

eth6
        WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:15

eth7
        WAN Miniport (IPv6)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:16

eth8
        WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:17

eth9
        WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:18

eth10
        WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:19

eth11
        Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:20

eth12
        Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:21

eth13
        Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
        MULTICAST mtu:-1 index:22

2018.02.15 09:38:55 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.HierarchyCircuitBreakerService] parent circuit breaker with settings [parent,type=PARENT,limit=22708224/21.6mb,overhead=1.0]
2018.02.15 09:38:55 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.request] creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [request,type=MEMORY,limit=19464192/18.5mb,overhead=1.0]
2018.02.15 09:38:55 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.fielddata] creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [fielddata,type=MEMORY,limit=19464192/18.5mb,overhead=1.03]
2018.02.15 09:38:55 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.in_flight_requests] creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [in_flight_requests,type=MEMORY,limit=32440320/30.9mb,overhead=1.0]
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Module execution: 66ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] TypeListeners creation: 8ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Scopes creation: 4ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Converters creation: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Binding creation: 4ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Private environment creation: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Injector construction: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Binding initialization: 3ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Binding indexing: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Collecting injection requests: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Binding validation: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Static validation: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Instance member validation: 1ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Provider verification: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Static member injection: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Instance injection: 0ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.i.i.Stopwatch] Preloading singletons: 1ms
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] node_sampler_interval[5s]
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup] -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 2
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] Platform: Windows
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] Java version: 8
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] java.nio.Buffer.address: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] direct buffer constructor: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable prior to Java9
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent0] java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: 32440320 bytes
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.CleanerJava6] java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop] -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop] -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
2018.02.15 09:38:56 TRACE app[][i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop] instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@69555c83
2018.02.15 09:38:56 TRACE app[][i.n.c.n.NioEventLoop] instrumented a special java.util.Set into: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@6cba52b5
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] adding address [{#transport#-1}{eLdEZAQ9SOatzX-UBU1KBg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}]
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.c.DefaultChannelId] -Dio.netty.processId: 804 (auto-detected)
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.netty.util.NetUtil] -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.netty.util.NetUtil] -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.netty.util.NetUtil] Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.netty.util.NetUtil] Failed to get SOMAXCONN from sysctl and file \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn. Default: 200
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.c.DefaultChannelId] -Dio.netty.machineId: 00:15:5d:ff:fe:02:44:6e (auto-detected)
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector] -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector] -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 0
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 0
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.PooledByteBufAllocator] -Dio.netty.allocator.useCacheForAllThreads: true
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.ByteBufUtil] -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.ByteBufUtil] -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
2018.02.15 09:38:56 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.ByteBufUtil] -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
2018.02.15 09:38:57 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xd5120a31] REGISTERED
2018.02.15 09:38:57 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xd5120a31] CONNECT: /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.15 09:38:58 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xd5120a31] CLOSE
2018.02.15 09:38:58 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xd5120a31] UNREGISTERED
2018.02.15 09:39:00 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{eLdEZAQ9SOatzX-UBU1KBg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], ignoring...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:570)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:407)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:319)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.addHostToClient(EsProcessMonitor.java:186)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.buildTransportClient(EsProcessMonitor.java:177)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.getTransportClient(EsProcessMonitor.java:160)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkStatus(EsProcessMonitor.java:134)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:93)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.isOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess.refreshState(SQProcess.java:162)
    at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess$EventWatcher.run(SQProcess.java:221)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9001
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2018.02.15 09:39:00 DEBUG app[][o.s.a.p.EsProcessMonitor] Connected to Elasticsearch node: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2018.02.15 09:39:01 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0x81cb7c2f] REGISTERED
2018.02.15 09:39:01 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0x81cb7c2f] CONNECT: /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.15 09:39:02 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0x81cb7c2f] CLOSE
2018.02.15 09:39:02 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0x81cb7c2f] UNREGISTERED
2018.02.15 09:39:02 DEBUG app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{eLdEZAQ9SOatzX-UBU1KBg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], ignoring...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.connectToChannels(Netty4Transport.java:362)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:570)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.openConnection(TcpTransport.java:117)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:407)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$ScheduledNodeSampler.run(TransportClientNodesService.java:390)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:9001
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:632)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd] REGISTERED
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd] CONNECT: /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] ACTIVE
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.request] [request] Adjusted breaker by [16440] bytes, now [16440]
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf] -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory] Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@2662f46f
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 32768
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2018.02.15 09:39:07 DEBUG app[][i.n.util.Recycler] -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] [length: 39, request id: 1, type: request, version: 5.0.0, action: internal:tcp/handshake] WRITE: 45B
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] FLUSH
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.request] [request] Adjusted breaker by [-16440] bytes, now [0]
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.T.tracer] [1][internal:tcp/handshake] sent to [{#transport#-1}{eLdEZAQ9SOatzX-UBU1KBg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}] (timeout: [null])
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] [length: 19, request id: 1, type: response, version: 5.0.0] READ: 25B
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] READ COMPLETE
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.request] [request] Adjusted breaker by [16440] bytes, now [16440]
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] [length: 47, request id: 2, type: request, version: 5.6.3, action: cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] WRITE: 53B
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] FLUSH
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] [length: 150, request id: 2, type: response, version: 5.6.3] READ: 156B
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0xe776a2fd, L:/127.0.0.1:51152 - R:/127.0.0.1:9001] READ COMPLETE
2018.02.15 09:39:07 TRACE app[][o.e.i.b.request] [request] Adjusted breaker by [-16440] bytes, now [0]
... [snipped due to length for post] ...
2018.02.15 09:39:20 TRACE app[][o.e.t.n.ESLoggingHandler] [id: 0x5f03831f, L:/127.0.0.1:51162 ! R:/127.0.0.1:9001] UNREGISTERED
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your sonar.properties file (after removing the sensitive information such as credentials, IPs) ?
Can you relaunch your SonarQube without DEBUG activated and post your sonar.log and es.log files ?

Comment: Are you using the [Build breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) plugin? Remove that plugin and try again.

Comment: We may have figured it out.  That target is a SQL 2008 R2 database, which may not be supported.  Testing against MySQL and SQL Express.